# Change css button to css active without link

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a problem. We have a top menu on our website with css styles. The problem is we have functions attached to the buttons, to simply set something on and off. But we cannot use the "active" css style becaus there is no url attached to this link. But we want to change the color of the button when it's active.

Can someone help us out with this ?

This is our menu html:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon one" id="box_one">buton one</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon two" id="box_two">button two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

This is triggering the functions, that part is working correctly. The function change() is in the function of myFunction!

```
document.getElementById('box_two').addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Css style of the part that should be active when click on button and off when click again on the button:

```
#actieflink:active {
padding-right: 16px;
background-color: #004D0e;
border-right: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work for me

```
function change() {
document.getElementById("actieflink").className='active';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have made an example here. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPRPJJ
Clicking on a link set it to active mode. 
clicking it again turns of active mode.
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, how can i add this to all menu buttons

Comment: check back the same link again. I have updated the example for 4 links

Comment: Great thanks!  One more little question. When a button is default loaded can i add some code to that function that is automatically loaded on site load.

Comment: you can alter that code to perform more tasks when the button is set to active or inactive, for example, calling some of your functions that you have prepared. You can also alter the css to make it looks the way you want.

Comment: `document.getElementById('radar_box').addEventListener("click", toggleButton);` should i add this to the function ?

Comment: listeners should be grouped together. when you look at the example I gave you, you should see 1 listener added to each of the 4 menu buttons. That is where you should put your listener code to. However, if you are creating elements dynamically when the menu button is clicked, then the addlistenerEvent code should be placed after the element creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on clicking `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon one" id="box_one">buton one</a>` it should append class name 'active' right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems I can see.
For starters :active is a not a class, and you can't set an active class with the className property.
Then there is this: actieflink:active . What is actifelink? When you use it like this in you css, you are telling you browser to look for an element of type actifelink. It will try and find an actifelink tag.
If you want to add an active class to your element, your change function should look something like this:

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("box_one").className += 'active';
}
```

or for a more abstract method

```
function change(elementId) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).className += 'active';
}
```

and the your css should look like this:

```
.active {
  /* active state style here */
}
```

If you want all your a tags on active state to have their own css you should do it like this:

```
a:active { 
   /* active state style here */
}
```

You should however not use className += as this will make it hard to toggle the class name. There are other alternatives. jQuery's toggleClass, addClass and removeClass methods will do great.
[jQuery class atribute](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

One other option is using [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) methods. But that might require some extra effort for older browsers support.